# Possible to change LabelFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say if I have this textbox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new {id = "add-name", data_parsley_maxlength = "1" })
```

How do I write my LabelFor so that it references "add-name"?

Or do I have to use @Html.Label?

Comment: what are you supplying for `LabelFor`? why are you overriding `id`?

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @for = "add-name" })` but why change the `id` from `id="Name"` to `id="add-name"`?